# PHP Decimal do DDD MM.MMM

Tags: php, gps

how made in PHP convert from Decimal (52.44554) to DDD MM.MMM?

Standard step is :

```
52 = N52° + 0.44554*60 => 26,732;   ===>  N52° 26,732
```

Comment: Is there no possible way for you to program this function yourself? Seems to me there's a standard mathematical formula for something like this.

Comment: http://geography.about.com/library/howto/htdegrees.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.  `$degrees` and `$minutes` would hold the values you were interested in.

```
$dec_degrees = 52.44554;
$degrees = floor($dec_degrees);
$dec_minutes = $dec_degrees - $degrees;
$minutes = 60 * $dec_minutes;
```

Comment: Mike Brant, thank you. Its nice and easy script. Thank you very much :))